# This SQL injection does not work, why?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I am trying one kind of SQL injection:

```
http://localhost/test/mysql.php?uid=1;%20DROP%20TABLE%20test
```

this URL should be equal to the statement:

```
SELECT username FROM test WHERE userid=1; DROP TABLE test
```

However, one error pop up when I open this URL:

```
Error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'drop table test' at line 1
```

It seems that 'drop table test' is put into one pair of quotes, but not being regarded as a statement. The corresponding php code is like this:

```
$SQL="select username from login where userid=".$userid;
$result=mysql_query($SQL);
```

I want to know why. Thanks for any helpful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query) does not support the execution of multiple statements at once:

> **`mysql_query()`** sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified **`link_identifier`**.

That’s also reflected by the MySQL error message that quotes everything after the `;` as unexpected.

Comment: If I want to let it work, what should I use? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql doesn't support **multiple query execution**

If you want so You just have to pass flag 65536 as mysql_connect's 5th parameter . the flag is defined in **[MySQL Client flags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.constants.php#mysql.client-flags)**.

```
#define CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS 65536 /* Enable/disable multi-stmt support */
#define CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS 131072 /* Enable/disable multi-results */
```

mysql_connect() should like somtehing for this:

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password, false, 65536);
```

Warning:

- You will get the result of mysql_query($query) for the first query
  only in the given $query . You can try concatenating  131072 with
  65536 for getting multiple results.
- This will not work on PHP < 4.3.0
- This will not work if sql.safe_mode is set as 1 in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing your SQL variable to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple, you should first parse uid=1, it should be integer or in any other case if it is string then you must restrict it to check length of uid according to your column name in db.